# How can a good player carry a game?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can someone tell me how to carry a game, because while I'm playing I can just see my score rise but my teammates fall, and I would like to know how I can help me and them to get a better game.

I am normaly playing top, and I'm winning my top like always, but not enough to carry a game or enough but how to do?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to figure out what you're asking about here... Can you try cleaning it up a little?

Comment: I would like to know about playstyle, shuold i afk farm. or gank aggresivly to help my team and let them get a good game and how would i be able to do thing like that. without destoy my top game?

Answer (score 4):

In case this answer is a TL;DR, I have highlighted the important parts in bold.

I have had to carry many games when I had teammates who were having trouble.

Often, when teams start to do badly, players begin to throw around blame and get mad at each other. As the leader of the team, make sure you **do not blame others and try to help calm everyone down** and motivate them to win. (This is hard to do sometimes, I can admit but **faking it well works too**)

Also, **make sure to communicate.** Example - Baron/Dragon is up, Enemy respawned, Protect inhib, etc.

I have found that small acts of kindness can motivate your team to win, such as giving them blue or red buff, or letting them get the kill during a chase.

Remember that **one fed champion is not enough to carry**, because the enemy can easily build  items to counter you.

**Warnings**

- If someone on your team is feeding, **avoid things such as typing /all 'Report "name" for feeding/lack of skill!**' This will only demoralize them from trying and will do nothing to help your team.
- **Try not to tell them they are feeding.** They know they are, and reassuring them about their poor play won't help.

AFK farming is probably not the best choice, especially in higher levels of play. If you have an obvious presence on your team, your team will begin to follow you. Ganking is very useful to your teammates when they are falling behind, but a word of advice-

- **Try not to take all the kills.** I understand as the carry it is the other player's job to feed you, but this mostly happens only in premade/ranked games. Try to split up the kills, because few solo queue players enter a game without thinking - 'I would like to get fed'

Good luck carrying!

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about specific champions, you want to pick a champion that scales incredibly well with farm. If your champion wins lane, it doesn't mean much if he doesn't snowball while your teammates lose their lanes. In addition, you want to pick champions that can also help win other lanes.

Examples that fulfill both of the above requirements are gangplank, shen, twisted fate, karthus (globals are pretty good at influencing other lanes) and any champion that can gank effectively.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to carry the game is to be an AD carry. They deal a ton of damage late game compared to solo top champions who are usually bruisers (tanky dps). However, league of legends is a team game and one person alone can not win the game by himself.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to win a game is to be a leader. You need to tell your team what to do when they have an advantage or disadvantage. Securing dragon, baron, towers, or kills are needed to win the game so help direct your team to do so.

Some personal tips for top lane are you can push to the enemy tower and run mid to try to secure a kill or even counter jungle the enemy jungler if you have a strong top laner like shyvanna.

Answer (score 1):

To carry a game, specifically from Top Lane, you need to first win your lane. After you push your opponent out of lane or kill him it is essential to make your presence known in other lanes or in the jungle. Unfortunately the current meta generally leaves top lane on an island which can make it difficult to have a presence around the map in the early laning phase. Anytime you leave your lane it is essential to push the creep wave to the tower before leaving.